# Select a select option element without a "selected" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is the thing:

I have a java app and it creates a group of selects based on a db. Also, if it happens that an element (let's call it product) has that value, it print the option with the selected attribute.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
    <option value="4">text4</option>
    <option value="5">text5</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
</select>
```

What i want to do is set in blank (set a value of zero) to the selects that not has an element with a selected value.

If you know another form to set to blank a list (diferent from put a default empty element in every select), please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this without an empty option, is to set the selectedIndex to -1

```
$('select:not(:has(option[selected]))').prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ex9p22yr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ex9p22yr/) `$('option:not(:selected)').val(0);` use `:not` and `:selected` and set the value to 0